# How is ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState supposed to be used

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, visualstatemanager

I have following visual state definitions:

```
<VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
    <ec:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
</VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Highlight">
        <VisualState x:Name="Active">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                To="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Inactive"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And some rectangles:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="A" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="4" />
<Rectangle x:Name="B" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="4" />
<Rectangle x:Name="C" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="4" />
<Rectangle x:Name="D" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="4" />
```

within my layout root stackpanel.

I want to apply the `Active` state to rectangles A and C. This feels like a job for `ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState`:

```
ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.A, "Active", true);
ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.B, "Inactive", true);
ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.C, "Active", true);
ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.D, "Inactive", true);
```

However, this doesn't work - the animation has no `Storyboard.TargetName` defined.

How can I get hold of the first argument passed to `GoToElementState` within the storyboard, so as to attach the animations to it?